# Was the firewall paradox resolved?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, general-relativity, black-hole-firewall

For quite sometime there has been a claim that the firewall paradox has been resolved (via lasers). For instance, http://global.ofweek.com/news/Lasers-to-solve-the-black-hole-information-paradox-9867 . I was wondering what the physics community thought about it? I haven't heard much of a reaction of the physics community. Why is this?

His paper: http://arxiv.org/abs/1310.7914

Comment: See the ref $3$ p $91$ of this [paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/1310.6335), and you see some activity... By the way, this paper is considered as one of the most serious objections against firewall (see chapter $4$ p $28$).

Answer (score 2):

I think it's fair to say that there is no consensus on the status of firewalls (which one might define as an answer to the question, "what does an observer falling through the horizon of an old black hole experience?").

I haven't read the paper you cite in detail, but a quick look through suggests that it doesn't address the AMPS argument. A resolution would require giving up on at least one of unitarity, EP at the horizon, or validity of EFT outside the stretched horizon. My interpretation of the paper (and the follow-up 1405.1097) is that Bradler/Adami would like to give up unitarity. This is something that is hard to swallow in a post-AdS/CFT world.